# I Can’t get derivatives (dFdx) working in my shader with WebGL1 or 2

Tags: three.js, glsl, shader, webgl, webgl2

I hope someone can help me with this. I am at the end of my rope, having gone through all of the discussions and examples I have found and still can’t get dFdx working, neither for WebGl1 or WebGL2. Partial code is shown below.

Thanks for you help.

The fragment shader uses:

```
#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable
precision highp float;

varying vec3 vNormal;
varying vec2 vUv;
varying vec3 vViewPosition;

uniform vec3 color;
uniform float animateRadius;
uniform float animateStrength;

vec3 faceNormal(vec3 pos) {
   vec3 fdx = vec3(dFdx(pos.x), dFdx(pos.y), dFdx(pos.z));  
   vec3 fdy = vec3(dFdy(pos.x), dFdy(pos.y), dFdy(pos.z));
   //vec3 fdx = dFdx(pos);
  //vec3 fdy = dFdy(pos);
  return normalize(cross(fdx, fdy));
}
```

The console shows the following:

```
THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error:  0 35715 false gl.getProgramInfoLog Must have an compiled fragment shader attached. <empty string> THREE.WebGLShader: gl.getShaderInfoLog() fragment
WARNING: 0:2: 'GL_OES_standard_derivatives' : extension is not supported
ERROR: 0:14: 'GL_OES_standard_derivatives' : extension is not supported
ERROR: 0:14: 'GL_OES_standard_derivatives' : extension is not supported
ERROR: 0:14: 'GL_OES_standard_derivatives' : extension is not supported
ERROR: 0:15: 'GL_OES_standard_derivatives' : extension is not supported
ERROR: 0:15: 'GL_OES_standard_derivatives' : extension is not supported
ERROR: 0:15: 'GL_OES_standard_derivatives' : extension is not supported1: #define lengthSegments 300.0
2: #extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable
3: precision highp float;
4: 
5: varying vec3 vNormal;
6: varying vec2 vUv;
7: varying vec3 vViewPosition;
```

Here is also part of the Javascript:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    const totalMeshes = isMobile ? 30 : 40;
    const isSquare = false;
    const subdivisions = isMobile ? 200 : 300;
    
    const numSides = isSquare ? 4 : 8;
    const openEnded = false;
    const geometry = createTubeGeometry(numSides, subdivisions, openEnded);
    // add to a parent container
    const container = new THREE.Object3D();
    const lines = [];
    //lines.length = 0;   
  
    ShaderLoader("scripts/Grp3D/Phys4646A2/tube.vert", "scripts/Grp3D/Phys4646A2/tube.frag", function (vertex, fragment) {
    const baseMaterial = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
        vertexShader: vertex,
        fragmentShader: fragment,
        side: THREE.FrontSide,
        extensions: {
        derivatives: true
        },
        defines: {
        lengthSegments: subdivisions.toFixed(1),
        ROBUST: false,
        ROBUST_NORMALS: false, 
        FLAT_SHADED: isSquare
        },
        uniforms: {
        thickness: { type: 'f', value: 1 },
        time: { type: 'f', value: 0 },
        color: { type: 'c', value: new THREE.Color('#303030') },
        animateRadius: { type: 'f', value: 0 },
        animateStrength: { type: 'f', value: 0 },
        index: { type: 'f', value: 0 },
        totalMeshes: { type: 'f', value: totalMeshes },
        radialSegments: { type: 'f', value: numSides },
        wavelength: { type: 'f', value: 2.0 }
        }
    });

    for( var i = 0; i < totalMeshes; i++){
        
        var t = totalMeshes <= 1 ? 0 : i / (totalMeshes - 1);
        
        var material = baseMaterial.clone();
        material.uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone(material.uniforms);
        material.uniforms.index.value = t;
        material.uniforms.thickness.value = randomFloat(0.005, 0.0075);
        material.uniforms.wavelength.value = 2.0;
        
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        mesh.frustumCulled = false; 
        lines.push(mesh);
        container.add(mesh);
    }   
    });
    
    return {
    object3d: container,
    update,
    setPalette
    };
        
    function update (dt,wvl) {
    dt = dt / 1000;
    lines.forEach(mesh => {
        //console.log(dt);
        mesh.material.uniforms.time.value += dt;
        mesh.material.uniforms.wavelength.value = wvl;
    });
    }
}; 

...
```

Comment: If the extension isn't supported, you can't *make* it be supported.

Comment: You said you tried WebGL 2, that'd mean you have WebGL 2 support in which case you should be able to just remove the `#extension`  statement and simply use the derivative functions by setting your shader version via the `#version es 3.0` statement.

Comment: @Nicol: This used to work fine just a few months ago (meaning the error did not come up). I don't know what could have changed (I am using Firefox, but also tried Chrome).

Comment: @LJ: Yes, I tried that. It complains that #version es 3.0 is not the first line in the shader, even though it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WebGL2 with version 300 es shaders they are supported by default, no extension needed.

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/build/three.module.js';

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

const material = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
  vertexShader: `#version 300 es
  in vec4 position;
  out vec4 vPosition;
  uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
  uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
  void main() {
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * position;
    vPosition = gl_Position;
  }
  `,
  fragmentShader: `#version 300 es
  precision mediump float;
  in vec4 vPosition;
  out vec4 outColor;
  void main() {
    outColor = vec4(normalize(vec3(dFdx(vPosition.x), dFdy(vPosition.y), 0)) * 0.5 + 0.5, 1);
  }
  `,
});

const geo = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry();
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, material);
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.add(mesh);
mesh.rotation.set(0.4, 0.4, 0);

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, 2, 0.1, 10);
camera.position.z = 3;

renderer.render(scene, camera);

</script>
```

Note:

```
const fs = `#version 300 es
...
`;
```

Has `#version 300 es` as the first line

```
const fs = `
#version 300 es
...
`;
```

Has `#version 300 es` as the 2nd line (error)

With WebGL1 your code should work but three.js auto-chooses WebGL2 if it exists. To test WebGL1 we could force it to WebGL1 by creating the WebGL context ourselves,

```
const canvas = document.querySelector(selectorForCanvas);
const context = canvas.getContext('webgl');
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas, context});
```

Or, we can use [a helper script](https://greggman.github.io/webgl-helpers/#webgl-disable2js) to effectively disable webgl2

```html
<script src="https://greggman.github.io/webgl-helpers/webgl2-disable.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/build/three.module.js';

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

const material = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
  vertexShader: `
  attribute vec4 position;
  varying vec4 vPosition;
  uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
  uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
  void main() {
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * position;
    vPosition = gl_Position;
  }
  `,
  fragmentShader: `
  #extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable
  precision mediump float;
  varying vec4 vPosition;
  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(normalize(vec3(dFdx(vPosition.x), dFdy(vPosition.y), 0)) * 0.5 + 0.5, 1);
  }
  `,
});

const geo = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry();
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, material);
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.add(mesh);
mesh.rotation.set(0.4, 0.4, 0);

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, 2, 0.1, 10);
camera.position.z = 3;

renderer.render(scene, camera);

</script>
```

Otherwise you can look at [`renderer.capabilities.isWebGL2`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.capabilities) to see if three.js choose WebGL2 and adjust your shaders as appropriate.

As for why your code used to work and doesn't work now, two ideas:

1. your machine didn't support WebGL2 before and now it does
2. you upgraded three.js to a version that chooses WebGL2 automatically and the previous version you were using didn't.

Comment: Thank you. It does appear to be the case that getContext only returns non-null for WebGL2. I don't know how to force webgl 1. I don't remember changing the three.js version but there was a browser update and there may have been a recent hardware drive update (from what I remember). Could that have been the cause? I had to make one additional change to make it work: The error I had regarding the #version statement not being on the first line was due to defines statement ```lengthSegments: subdivisions.toFixed(1),``` in the RawShaderMaterial call. I had to move that to the shader code itself.

Comment: I guess one last question is what happens when someone calls a website with a shader written for webgl 2 but that person's machine only supports webgl 1? But I suppose that's another topic.

Comment: It fails. Like it says at the bottom of my answer, you can check the flag and adjust your shaders. You can get some idea of how three.js does this for its built in shaders [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/3c60484ce033e0dc2d434ce0eb89fc1f59d57d65/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram.js#L672)

Comment: @Marquizzo, that's already in the answer ;)